# Change the color of particular cell in datagrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-mobile

I'm using VS 2008 to create a Windows Mobile program in C#. I need to display data in a grid. The only grid control I could find for Windows Mobile is DataGrid, so I placed one on my form. I now need to change the color of particular cell according to some condition. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure if it is helpful or not. Is it possible to handle cell paint event? For each cell you can fill the rectangle with the desired color in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Usually grids have some kind of "fetching" event; your best solution is a row fetching or, at worst, a cell fetching event.
Listening to this, you can trap the moment when the row/cell is being created and apply your style logic. This is true for grids spanning from VB6 to Asp.NET, so I suppose can apply on your case too.

Hope this helps!
mt